# error while loading shared libraries: libsandbox.so

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, sandbox, autoconf

When I try to run the .out file after compiling the sandbox c program, it gives the following error:

```
    ./sandbox: error while loading shared libraries: libsandbox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "**shared library gone missing**" problem is not unique to `libsandbox`. It so happens to many self-compiled libraries that use GNU autotools for build configuration.

The problem is that GNU autotools prepares the library to go to `/usr/local/lib` by default (and there are good reasons for this setting to remain default, such as [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) conformance). However, in some Linux distributions -- like **Ubuntu** and **ArchLinux** -- the runtime linker (aka. `ld.so`) does *not* search `/usr/local/lib` for shared libraries, unless otherwise specified through `ldconfig`.

While all other solutions from @anton-kovalenko's answer are viable, it could be more convenient if you just configure `libsandbox` with options `--prefix=/usr` and `--libdir=/usr/lib` (in case you have write access to `/usr/lib`, of course). Or you can add a new `ldconfig` entry in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` to enable `/usr/local/lib` for library search at system level.

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of `libsandbox`.

Answer (score 1):

You do the following:

1. First you find where you copy of `libsandbox.so` is. It's likely to be somewhere if you successfully linked against it.
2. Then you try with `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/directory/of/your/libsandbox/copy/ ./sandbox` and see if it works.
3. Then you decide how to deploy your program together with the library, so it works on the target machine. There are many possibilities: `gcc -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'` for linking would make `libsandbox.so` loadable from the executable's directory. A wrapper script which takes care of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is another solution. Putting `libsandbox.so` into a location where dynamic linker can find it is another one.